# Unable to configure Hikaricp 2.2.5 with Java 6

Tags: java, spring, hikaricp

I have a Spring java web application. I am trying to use Hikaricp 2.2.5 for connection pooling with the following configuration.

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP-java6</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

**XML:**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
     <property name="minimumIdle" value="5"/>
     <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="200"/>
     <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"/>
     <property name="username" value="root"/>
     <property name="password" value="root"/>
     <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
     <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app"/>
     <property name="autoCommit" value="true"/>
     <property name="connectionTimeout" value="30000"/>
     <property name="idleTimeout" value="600000"/>
     <property name="maxLifetime" value="1800000"/>
     <property name="poolName" value="LoginPool"/>
</bean>
```

I am getting the following error `NoSuchMethodError`.

**Exception Stack Trace:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.sql.Connection.getNetworkTimeout()I
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PoolUtilities.isJdbc41Compliant(PoolUtilities.java:245)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.addConnection(HikariPool.java:412)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.fillPool(HikariPool.java:500)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:159)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:110)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2006)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1289)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    ... 109 more
```

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Judging from the stacktrace you aren't actually using 2.2.5 but 2.2.4. See [this issue](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/188).

Comment: @M.Deinum I have also seen the same issue. But, I think I have the mentioned maven configuration. I have HikariCP-java6-2.2.5 jar in my maven repo.

Comment: Make sure that it is also used by your application that you don't have an old version somewhere in your classpath. Maybe try deleting the one from your repo and retrieve it again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that issue is fixed. As stated make sure you don't have other references or copies of old jars hanging around. Make sure you haven't put older versions some where in your server...

Comment: @M.Deinum I checked thoroughly. Tomcat lib also does not have any. This is for the first time I got this jar. No local maven repo jars also. Only 2.2.5 is the jar.

Comment: The `isJdbc41Compliant` method doesn't even exist in the 2.2.5 jar... Hence my suggestion there is something wrong in your environment.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you. Intellij didn't build the new war. I resolved it.

Comment: @M.Deinum How to provide the jdbcUrl value? Should it include database schema also? Like jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app?

Comment: You shouldn't provide a `jdbcUrl` instead use `serverName` and `databaseName` properties.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks a lot. How to have minimum number of connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things.  The exception in your stacktrace:

`at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.addConnection(HikariPool.java:412)`

[does not line up with](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/2.2.5/hikaricp-java6/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.java#L412) a call to `isJdbc41Compliant()` in the 2.2.5 branch.  That [code was removed](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/commit/ca054975daa0540be4347b973712cc9b374e5565) in 2.2.5.  Second, if you are using 2.2.5 and you are setting `jdbcUrl` you do not need `dataSourceClassName`, they are mutually exclusive.  Try a clean build, and as a last resort go into your .m2/repositories directory and find and delete all HikariCP artifacts and let them re-download.

UPDATE: lastly, make sure you are using the latest MySQL driver if possible.